# What was the "rigorous" definition of "number" for the Pythagoreans?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, numbers, pythagoras

I am not sure if this is the right stackexchange for this question. However, I'm wondering about the following thing:

We know n+ow that there are **rational** and **irrational** numbers. Pythagoras however, believed that

> Pythagorean conjecture: "**all numbers are rational**".

I am thinking about how this conjecture can be deductively proven to be false within the Pythagorean system. For that we need a definition of "number", so that we can say:

> 1. The square root of two is a number.
> 2. The square root of two is not rational.
> 3. Therefore not all numbers are rational.

My question is essentially about how we can deductively show that (1.) is correct, based on the Pythagorean definition. **That is why I am wondering: What is the definition of "number" for the Pythagoreans on the basis of which statement (1) is true.**

Nevertheless when I look for a definition online, I only read vague statements like "numbers are the source of all things".

Comment: Pythagorean does **not** conjectured: "all numbers are rational".

Comment: There are no extant sources of [Pythagoras](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pythagoras/).

Comment: One of the basic doctrine of [Pythagoreanism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pythagoreanism/) was that [number is what allows things to be known and understood by us](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philolaus/#EpiRolNum).

Comment: Number, as per the ancient Greek tradition, is **natural** number : "Number, indeed, has two proper kinds, odd and even".

Comment: For discussion, you can see the post [irrationality-of-the-square-root-of-2](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2/irrationality-of-the-square-root-of-2) and [pythagoras-vs-the-idea-of-pythagoras](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/391/pythagoras-vs-the-idea-of-pythagoras) and [did-pythagoras-school-collapse-because-of-their-discovery-of-irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571998/did-pythagoras-school-collapse-because-of-their-discovery-of-irrational-numbers).

Comment: Conclusion: there were no any "rigorous" definition (in the modern sense) of *number* in Ancient Greece.

Answer (score 1):

Vihart from youtube has a video explaining this. The answer to your question is answered at 4:00 to 6:57. Here it is below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1E7I7_r3Cw